# Draw an image over another image

Tags: codenameone

I have an EncodedImage. I want to draw a FontImage over it to get another EncodedImage. It’s similar to a LayeredLayout (a layer over another layer), but in this case I need a new EncodedImage with the two images merged.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a mutable image.

```
Image img = Image.create(encImage.getWidth(), encImage.getHeight(), 0);
Graphics g = img.getGraphics();
g.drawImage(encImage, 0, 0);
g.drawImage(fontImage.scaled(encImage.getWidth(), encImage.getHeight()).toImage(), 0, 0);
```